# How to export private appointments in outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, ics

So trying to help someone convert their Outlook calendar to ics to share online.   Works fine... But like 50% of their entries were manually marked private.   I have tried checking the "Include details of items marked private".   This will send their stuff to ics but it just shows Private Appointment and they need the name of the meeting/whatever.   So is there a way to mass unprivate these entries or get this from an export?

Comment: I can recommend the software you can use to mass-unprivate calendar items.

Comment: Have you in File > Save Calendar > More Options, set Detail to "Full details" ?

Comment: @harrymc - Yes - it just shows private appointment for every entry on export.

Comment: Do you mean that everything is correctly exported, except that all the appointments are marked private? As the ics file is pure text, you may fix that using a text-editor or a text-editing batch utility. Would that solve the problem? If you are interested, post such an ics file with one appointment so I can recommend a utility.

Answer (score 1):

You say you have managed to export all Outlook appointments and your only
problem is that they are all marked as private.

This is easy to correct, as the ics file is a text file,
where each appointment looks like this:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
...
```

> **CLASS:PRIVATE**

```
...
END:VEVENT
```

You need to either delete the CLASS clause, as the default is public,
or change `CLASS:PRIVATE` to `CLASS:PUBLIC`.

To delete the line, you could use a batch command (in a .bat file)
to copy the file without these lines :

```
findstr /v CLASS:PRIVATE input.ics > output.ics
```

You may of course just use a text editor to replace all occurrences of
`CLASS:PRIVATE` to `CLASS:PUBLIC`.

**Exporting all appointments**

For the benefit of future readers, here is how to export all the
appointments in a calendar.

1. Open Outlook, and then click **Calendar** at the bottom
2. Select the calendar that you want to convert from the the left-hand pane
3. Open the File pull-down menu, and then click **Save Calendar**
4. Choose **iCalendar Format (*ics)** from the **Save As Type** pull-down menu, and then click **More Options**

[image: image1]

5. Open the Date Range pull-down menu and select **Whole Calendar**
   to convert the entire calendar
6. Open the menu next to **Detail** and specify **Full Availability**
   to include all the details of the appointments
7. Click the **Show**. To include items marked as private,
   check the box next to **Include details of items marked private**

[image: image2]

8. Click **OK**
9. Specify folder and file names
10. Click **Save**

Answer (score 1):

There actually apparently is no way to solve this problem without changing the items in Outlook first.

Even though checking the "Include details of items marked private" box does save the dates and starting and ending times of private items in the ICS file, it does NOT include any of the actual meeting information such as title, people, etc. All it does is that it includes the private items, instead of leaving them out of the ICS file completely.

Yes, one would think that "details" would mean actual details, not just date and time. But that is not the case.

Editing the ICS to remove the CLASS: PRIVATE from items, as suggested here, does NOT allow one to see the actual content of the item because no such information is saved in the ICS file. The title of the item will be "Private appointment" even if you set class to public.

The only workaround I can think of is to remove the private label from these meetings **in Outlook** but put in some other marker that they are private. Then save the ICS file, then go into that file and edit the CLASS to be private on those items, searching for them based on the marker created. Seems like quite a bit of manual labor, unless there is some way to do both steps as a batch.

Answer (score 0):

During the export in Outlook, before saving the ICS:

1. In the dialog click "More Options"
2. Choose "Show >>" to show the "extended options"
3. Activate the checkbox "Include details of items marked private"
4. OK
5. Save ICS

[image]

Now you have all details of the elements in the ICS file. 
If you need to "unprivate" the elements for further use, open the ICS file with any notepad and replace all occurences of `CLASS:PRIVATE` with `CLASS:PUBLIC`.